# Clarification on JUnit5 documention on setup of Maven dependencies

Tags: maven, junit, documentation, junit5

The JUnit5 pages request clarification questions to be posted on StackOverflow so here it is.

The [User Guide](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/) says JUnit 5 = JUnit Platform + JUnit Jupiter + JUnit Vintage, and that JUnit Platform is a "foundation for launching testing frameworks". So JUnit Platform sounds pretty essential.

It also says "To find out what artifacts are available for download and inclusion in your project, refer to [Dependency Metadata](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#dependency-metadata)." When you go there, information about JUnit Platform, 10.1.1. JUnit Platform, Group ID: org.junit.platform, Version: 1.6.2 is listed first. So it makes it sound like you have to include it in your dependencies.

However, the User Guide also recommends going to [Build Support](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-build). There, Maven instructions recommend the inclusion of `maven-surefire-plugin`, `maven-failsafe-plugin`, `junit-jupiter-api` and `junit-jupiter-engine`.

The User Guide also suggests looking into [Example Projects](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#overview-getting-started-example-projects). There, the Maven example only includes artifact `junit-jupiter`.

So my question is: which suggestion to follow? What are the actual instructions?

For the common end user, it seems the best option is to follow the Example Project. However, it shows as the last suggestion in the User Guide page, and seems to contradict explanations coming before it. This creates a bit of unnecessary guesswork and I would suggest streamlining this part of the User Guide to go more directly to the point.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `junit-jupiter` which is a module that will include both `junit-jupiter-api` and `junit-jupiter-engine`.

```java
/**
 * Aggregates all JUnit Jupiter modules.
 *
 * @since 5.4
 */
module org.junit.jupiter {
    requires transitive org.junit.jupiter.api;
    requires transitive org.junit.jupiter.engine;
    requires transitive org.junit.jupiter.params;
}
```

This pom seems ok to start (found [here](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5-samples/blob/r5.6.2/junit5-jupiter-starter-maven/pom.xml)), as linked from:

> For Maven, check out the junit5-jupiter-starter-maven project.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit5-jupiter-starter-maven</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>${maven.compiler.source}</maven.compiler.target>
        <junit.jupiter.version>5.6.2</junit.jupiter.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.jupiter.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.2</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

So:

1. create pom.xml as above
2. create test class in src/test/java/org/example/MyExampleTest.java:

```java
package org.example;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;

class MyExampleTest {

  @Test
  void thisFailsTest() {
    fail(); //start here
  }

}
```

3. execute from a terminal `mvn test`
4. The build will fail like this

```
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.2:test (default-test) @ junit5-jupiter-starter-maven ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Running org.example.MyExampleTest
[ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.017 s <<< FAILURE! - in org.example.MyExampleTest
[ERROR] thisFailsTest  Time elapsed: 0.014 s  <<< FAILURE!
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: 
    at org.example.MyExampleTest.thisFailsTest(MyExampleTest.java:10)

[INFO] 
[INFO] Results:
[INFO] 
[ERROR] Failures: 
[ERROR]   MyExampleTest.thisFailsTest:10
[INFO] 
[ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

5. remove fail() and start a useful test :)

Comment: Thanks. I agree that the Example Project suggestion, which corresponds to yours, is the way to go. My question was largely target at their improving the page. I will wait a bit to accept your question to improve the chance they see this.

Comment: I’d suggest you create an issue on Github which points to this SO question. Or even a pull request with the correct recommendation.

Comment: If you want to use JPMS modularity then use the latest version of Surefire and follow this page https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/jpms.html
If you do not use JPMS, follow the link https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/junit-platform.html